# Run App Engine development server with modules in PyCharm

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm

Since the latest release of the Google App Engine Python SDK, it's possible to use [modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/). I have a Python application with a default module and another module. To start the module in the development server, the development server has to be run like this:

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml othermodule.yaml
```

When I add `app.yaml othermodule.yaml` to "Additional options" in the Run/Debug configuration of PyCharm and then run the development server, I get the following error message:

> google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.errors.InvalidAppConfigError: "."
>   is a directory and a yaml configuration file is required

This is because PyCharm adds a dot at the end of the command to run the development server, like this:

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml othermodule.yaml .
```

Is it possible to remove the dot, or do I have to wait until this is fixed in PyCharm? Before there were modules, there was no need for this.

Comment: I created an issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10675

Comment: Same issue here. In the mean time, I have to execute SDK server from command line.

Answer (score 6):

You can go around this for the time being by just creating a new Run Configuration.
Chose Python configuration, then fill like this:

- script: `/path/to/your/dev_appserver.py`
- script parameters: `dispatch.yaml module1.yaml module2.yaml`
- working directory: `/path/to/your/appengine/project`

It works just fine like this for me. The dispatcher is launching properly and I've got all the logs like before in PyCharm.

Comment: This works fine for running your application, but not for debugging because the debugger needs a (random?) port number. The workaround is to debug each module on its own. You don't need to include `dispatch.yaml` in the script parameters by the way.

Comment: FYI now the issue has been fixed, you don't have to create a new configuration anymore, just add the "script parameters" to the Appengine configuration in Pycharm for your project and it will work. Also including the dispatch.yaml is not mandatory but very much useful as you won't have to specify the module port when accessing an url from a module.