# Pycharm Run server error no app.yaml file at '.' for google app engine project

Tags: google-app-engine, pycharm

I'm pretty new with Pycharm and since this morning i have tried different configuration to use the **Run** command with an existing Google app engine project but without success.

I have a pretty clear error :)

`google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.errors.AppConfigNotFoundError: no app.yaml file at '.'`

Nothing wrong with that because the existing project use a custom file call **app_dev.yaml**. So it's normal that Pycharm is unable to load the server.

How can i change this behaviour and tell Pycharm to use **app_dev.yaml** instead of app.yaml?
Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: I'd be surprised if GAE can be made to work with a file called anything other then app.yaml.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood Actually the project run and work with another file than app.yaml. You can make it work with dev_appserver.py --skip_sdk_update_check yes --log_level debug /path/to/file/app.dev.yaml (for example) Last argument of dev_appserver.py can be a custom name yaml file.

Comment: I can't make it work with Pycharm because they append a '.' after the last argument. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9714. So it failed when i use they run command.

Comment: Color me surprised then! Good to know, thxs.

Comment: More detail. In that jetbrains ticket, they closed it and said to remove the "app.yml" from the command to make it run. In other words, it seems they use the dot to refer to app.yml.

Answer (score 0):

I input an app.yaml on root directory and reloading my project, this working for me.

Comment: Can you extend more your answer or otherwise post this as a comment instead of an answer (from review)?

Answer (score 0):

While the [PY-9714](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9714) issue was, indeed, closed without a resolution, the automatic '.' added to the `Run` configuration has been reconsidered in [PY-10675](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10675) in light of GAE support for multiple modules/services inside the same application and/or request routing using a `dispatch.yaml` file.

So in the more recent PyCharm versions it's possible to specify one or more `.yaml` files as options in the `Run` configuration. See for an example [Pycharm multiple modules Run server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828218/pycharm-multiple-modules-run-server?rq=1)

For those still running an older Pycharm version without the fix, a solution using a wrapper script is described in [Run App Engine development server with modules in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442956/run-app-engine-development-server-with-modules-in-pycharm?rq=1)