# Google App Engine on PHPStorm 10

Tags: google-app-engine, phpstorm

I have trouble running/debugging Google App Engine application from PHPStorm lately. It seems that PHPStorm adds a dot ( . ) at the end of the command when running dev_appserver.py

```
/usr/bin/python /Users/maksim/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py app.yaml ember.yaml dispatch.yaml --php_executable_path=/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php55/php-cgi --host=0.0.0.0 --enable_sendmail=true .

dev_appserver.py: error: unrecognized arguments: .

Process finished with exit code 2
```

When I run the command without dot from my terminal, it is working perfectly.

```
/usr/bin/python /Users/maksim/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py app.yaml ember.yaml dispatch.yaml --php_executable_path=/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php55/php-cgi --host=0.0.0.0 --enable_sendmail=true
```

How can I fix this? Can JetBrains team update the plugin for Google App Engine or is there a workaround to remove that dot from being added to the script?[image]

EDIT: forgot to add Google App Engine SDK version which is release: "1.9.28"

Comment: I opened a ticket at JetBrains issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-29845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem with PyCharm/python.

Creating a custom Run configuration for my project as suggested in this answer worked for me: [Run App Engine development server with modules in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442956/run-app-engine-development-server-with-modules-in-pycharm), a similar solution *might* work for PHPStorm.

Comment: Thanks Dan for pointing that out. I think I need to create a issue ticket to JetBrains guys. I am not sure is it possible to debug application when running a custom Run configuration... that is the main reason for me.

Comment: At least in pycharm it's called a Run/Debug configuration, I guess it *might* work for debugging as well. But I can't really confirm as I have yet to learn how to use the pycharm debugger :)